# Create sdcard0 symlink on 6.0.1 for WhatsApp compatibility

Tags: applications, internal-storage, nexus-5, whatsapp-messenger, file-system

I recently switched from a Galaxy S2 running CM 10.2 (Android 4.3.1) to a Nexus 5 running 6.0.1 (stock rooted).

My goal was to migrate all my WhatsApp data (history, media, etc.) over to the new device. Restoring the history was no problem using WhatsApp's builtin backup/restore functionality.
I then proceeded to copy all the `.../WhatsApp/Media/` folders over to the new phone, however, I still got an error message stating that the file could not be found when trying to open any (old) received images or videos from within WhatsApp.

Upon further investigation, it seems like WhatsApp is (or was?) storing the absolute path to every individual media file in its database, e.g. on my S2: `/storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20140813-WA0020.jpg`
It just so happens that the `/storage/sdcard0` symlink doesn't exist on my Nexus 5 and hence WhatsApp can't access older files since the links are broken.

So I figured all I needed to do was create the `/storage/sdcard0` symlink, like this:

```
ln -s /sdcard /storage/sdcard0
```

Confirmation:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # ls -l /storage
drwx--x--x root     sdcard_rw          1970-07-07 17:59 emulated
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-12-30 16:26 sdcard0 -> /sdcard
drwxr-xr-x root     root              1970-07-09 08:57 self
```

Unfortunately, WhatsApp still couldn't access my old media files (not to mention that the symlink was gone after a reboot).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I did some more testing and noticed that the `/storage/sdcard0` symlink is still there in versions prior to Marshmallow (I tested factory images of 5.0, 5.0.1 and 5.1.1 plus a friend's N5 running 4.4.4).

For now I have downgraded to 5.1.1 (with an intact `/storage/sdcard0` symlink) and my old WhatsApp media now works as expected.

It's still very odd that the symlink didn't exist/work on 6.x though.

Comment: In my Android Lollipop: `sdcard` is a symlink to `/sdcard/emulated/legacy` && `sdcard0` is a symlink to `/sdcard/emulated/legacy` && `legacy` is a symlink to `/mnt/shell/emulated/0`. There are other things to consider, such the group of the directories and the files.